# Communicating between Backbone Views

Tags: backbone.js

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend( {

   events: {
       'click #selector' : 'onClick'
    },

   onClick: function( event ) {

   }
})
```

Is the `onClick` event above global to all Views or is it only the containing View that will intercept it?

Say I have another View that wants to react when onClick is called, what is the best way of doing that?

Should I be namespacing my events such as `MyView:onClick` or is this not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the onClick event above global to all Views or is it only the containing View that will intercept it?

Backbone uses delegated events which means all event listeners are bound to the view's root element (`this.el`). Thus events are visible only to one particular view instance.

> Say I have another View that wants to react when onClick is called, what is the best way of doing that?

The purest backbone way is to make a model instance shared by both views and have the view that gets clicked change the model, perhaps like `this.selectionModel.set('selected', true);`. This model will represent the state shared across views. It doesn't necessarily have to be state destined for a server-side database to fit the MVC paradigm.

Another viable option though would be to have the view itself emit the event:

```
onClick: function (event) {
  this.trigger('click', event); //or 'selected' might be better
}
```

Then you could bind the event handlers between source view and destination view in your router.

> Should I be namespacing my events such as MyView:onClick or is this not necessary?

Not when you have a small codebase and a small number of events. However, I would make the event names at the backbone layer domain specific and not duplicate the browser's generic UI  input event names. So instead of "click" consider "select" or "activate" or whatever makes sense given your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

I know three ways of how to call an event:

**First:** Commonly way, it know everyone. the way is call event inside its view(i think, you  don't need any example)

**Second:** Calling event `parent`(it does not mean extend) view. For example:

```
<body> 
  <div id="content">

    <div id="view1" >
      <input type="checkbox" id="first_view_element">
    </div> 
    <div id="view2" >
      <input type="checkbox" id="second_view_element">
    </div> 

  </div> 
</body>
```

if so: parent view's `el` is '#content' and child view's `el` is '#view1', you can write inside parent view

```
  events: {
    'click #first_view_element' : 'onClick'
  }
```

**Third:** Calling event inside completely different view. In this case, I try use above html code to explain. If  one view's `el` is '#view1' and another's `el` is '#view2'

```
App.hendChangesObj = 0 // it was simple name, i couldn't find variable name and param
App.View1 = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
   'click #first_view_element' : 'onClick'
  },

  onClick: function( event ) {
    App.hendChangesObj++;
  }

});
App.View2 = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(App.hendChangesObj, "change", this.onClick);
  },

  onClick: function() {
    // do something 
  }

});
```